# objects don't show up

Tags: mesh, objects

I must've accidentally touched some key because all of the objects except the one i was workin with have dissapeared, and don't show up even with the visible toggle on
Also if i select them they're stuck in Object Mode and I can go to any other mode

[image]

Here's the mesh http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=35648957213405038207

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67490/why-does-my-object-not-show-up

Comment: Yep, probably #6 from "Invisible to viewport"

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you pressed <kbd>/</kbd> to go to "local object view". Just press it again to show all the other objects.